# Deducing the order of a group by its generators.

Tags: group-theory

I have a group $G = \langle  (1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3) \rangle $ and I want to show its order is $60$. First, I noted since $G$ has an element of order $3$ and $5$ in, its order is a factor of $15$.

Then I have shown that $(3,4,5)$ is in $G$, and by these two permutations stabilise $2$ unique points, so $G$ is also a factor of $4$, so $|G| \geq 60$. Then since $G$ is clearly a subgroup of $S_{5}$ which isn't $S_{5}$, its order must be $60$ (which would obviously mean that $G = A_{5}$).

Is this reasoning correct? I feel like there's something a little wrong here.

Comment: More clarity on why $G$ isn't $S_5$ would be good.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with your reasoning is the "obvious" part: it could be true that $S_5$ has other subgroups of order $60$ besides the alternating group $A_5$.

However, if you could verify that $G$ is contained in $A_5$ then your proof would be complete.

Comment: Sorry, should have written this part up. I say its clear as $G$ will not contain any odd permutations so it isn't $S_5$ itself. Since $|G| \mid |S_5| = 120$, $|G| = 60$. i believe the only subgroup of $S_5$ is $A_5$, but i wouldn't be sure how to prove this. Also, im not sure how i would show that $G$ was contained in $A_5$ (maybe i can use its a group of order 60 with only even permutations??)

Comment: Do you know the fact that $A_5$ is *precisely* the group of even permutations? And from what you write in your comment, you do seem to know the fact that the product of two even permutations is an even permutation.